# SQM: Warning: Failed to upload all unsent reports. [HRESULT = 0x80004005 - E_FAIL]

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update, sccm-2012

I am trying to deploy some patches to a windows server 2012 R2, but they are failing even after have tried below things(which eventually did not gave any error).
From the %windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.logs, I could see below error attached as image.[errorlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t6EZ.jpg)
[errorlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBfwA.jpg)

Can anyone please help on that.

Regards,
Avisekh Das

Comment: These images don't capture the exact error source! I'd suggest you to either upload CBS.log file somewhere on the cloud for analysis, or capture the relevant section at the timestamp when the error occured (at reboot highly likely/ clicking on Install updates).

Comment: I found it was coming due to cbs corruption as it was seen it cbs.log
using dism.exe I repaired the cbs and it worked.